# What happened to John White and his brother or sister?

Tags: england, 20th-century, census-records, wales

All information below was obtained through ancestry.co.uk.

My Great Grandfather, Thomas White was one of 6 children born to Baldwin White, b1862 in Salcombe, Devon & Rachel Arminia Fox, b1864 in Wayland, Norfolk. They were married in Falmouth, Cornwall in 1896.

On the [1901 census](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:X9Y9-V67) (Ref: RG 13/4962), Baldwyn (Baldwin) White and Rachel A. White (Nee Fox) were living in Newport, Monmouthshire, Wales with 4 Children:

1. Beatrice A. White, 4 yrs
2. Baldwyn White, 2 yrs
3. John White, 1 yr
4. Thomas White, 3 weeks

According to the [1911 census](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:X7LT-1L7) in Falmouth, Cornwall, England (Ref: RG 14/13895/129) Baldwin White and Rachel A. White had given birth to 6 children, but only 3 survived:

1. John White, 11yrs
2. Thomas White, 10yrs
3. Jane White, 7yrs

Some connected family trees on Ancestry.co.uk have John as being one of the 3 infant deaths, but seeing as he appears on the 1911 census I don't believe this to be true.

My Great Grandfather, as far as I am aware, only ever spoke of his younger sister Jane.

I have run into a bit of a brick wall, I know that Baldwin Jr and Beatrice were definitely two of the 3 deaths. They appear on the BMD death index for Newport, Monmouthshire, but I can't find any reference to John White after 1911 that I can be certain is my Great Grand Uncle & have found no reference at all to the 6th (as yet unknown) child who I assume was born and died at some point between 1901 & 1911.

If it helps at all, the BMD Birth index for John White is:
Qtr Jan-Feb-Mar 1900
District - Newport
County - Monmouthshire
Vol - 11a
Page - 223

I know that the family was raised in Newport and, due to ill health on the fathers part, moved to Falmouth in Cornwall in 1908.

Comment: Have edited the information about the 1911 census to clarify which children were reported in the census. This edit was made without seeing the census, so hope you will make sure it still reads as intended.

Comment: Question: Was Jane White reported to be ae 11, as above, in the 1911 census? (If so, she would appear older than Thomas, not a "younger sister.")

Comment: @GeneJ Jane was 7 at the time of the 1911 census, John was 11. It is John that I want to find out more about after 1911 and another sibling who isn't on the 1901 census but must have died before the 1911.

Comment: @Fortiter thanks for correcting my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well an obvious problem here is that `John White` is a fairly common name, so pinning down his death is likely to take a bit of work...

The first thing to do on that front would be to obtain the birth certificate, which will give you a precise date of birth. Assuming that he didn't die in infancy, and lived to a reasonable age, then he will hopefully have died after full birth dates started being included in the index of deaths which should make identifying his date and place of death easier.

Finding the sixth child is a whole other challenge - children who are born and die in infancy without every appearing in a census can be very hard to find especially with a relatively common surname. Short of looking at every `White` born in Newport in that period the best hope may be if you can find baptismal records for the other children and then look through the register for some trace of the sixth child.

Comment: When did the full birth dates start being included in the death index?

Comment: Sometime in 1969 by the looks of things (Q4 has it but Q1 doesn't) so it's probably going to be a close thing in this case.